# Error in void definition when trying to get file path

Tags: c++, function, filepath, void

I'm making a void definition to easily get a path to a file but char "filename[]" does not want to be set to another file. What can I do?

```
#include <windows.h>
void getPath(char file)
{
    char filename[] = file;
    char s[MAX_PATH];
    GetFullPathName(filename, MAX_PATH, s, nullptr);
}
```

Comment: A `char` is only a single character. For strings you probably want a `const char *` or, since you tagged it C++, a `std::string`.